# Generating/Printing custom reports using MEF?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I have an application that generates reports for the end user.  These are `DevExpress XtraReports`.   One user may want a report with certain fields in some format while another user may want the same fields or more in a different format.  Instead of doing something like:

```
if(user == "")
   //print report for this user
   PrintReport(user);
else
  //print report for other user
  PrintReport(user)
```

I thought it would be good to use `MEF` here and create some `IPrintReport` interface and have `MEF` manage which report should print depending on which assembly is in the directory for my `PrintReport` method.  Is this a good scenario to use `MEF` or is there a better or more simpler way to handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a situation where `MEF` could be used to solve your problem, but there is one question I would ask myself first:

- Do I need to add additional report formats without recompiling your main application?

If not, I think that `MEF` is overkill for this situation. The main benefit I have seen from using `MEF` is that modules of my application can be developed independently from the main application. I don't need to republish my entire application to fix a little bug in one of it's components. I can simply drop my new .dll in a folder and my application will start using it.

If you answered no to the question above, I would not use `MEF` for this. Instead I would create that `IPringReport` interface you mentioned. All classes implementing this interface could be listed in your application settings where the user could select their desired format. If your users don't want to deal with selecting a format, you could simply have a settings file that sets it for them.